# append later not remove

Tags: jquery, function, append

```
<div class="cast">
   <p id="addnew">
      <input type="text"><b id="add">ADD</b>
  </p>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#addnew").append("<p><input type=\"text\"><u id=\"del\">delete<u></p>");
    });
    $('#ab').click(function(){
       alert(); 
    });
});
```

I clicked `#add`. Append `<p><input type=\"text\"><u id=\"del\">delete<u></p>`
later click `#del`. No function.

I have two  ajax functions. Call PHP include html code

Comment: May be markup not able to find `#del` to apply any event

Comment: you have to add the event after you append the input and change the selector to del. https://jsfiddle.net/u457sy18/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `on` to bind your `del` click event :

```
$(document).on("click","#del", function(e) {
...
});
```

You can find the documentation on `on` here :http://api.jquery.com/on/